# How to get the file path when it contains non ascii characters using CFileDialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using CFileDialog and try to load file with the name like "VERİLERİ.txt". When I call

```
Ctring filePath = fileDialog.GetPathName();
```

Instead of a valid file name I get VERI?LERI?.txt, becasue CFileDialog doesn't recognize characters like 'İ'.

Can any one suggest the possible solution?

Comment: Did you compile your code with Unicode support enabled?

Comment: @PaulSanders no I am compiling it with Multi-Byte Character Set.

Comment: Ok, can you switch to Unicode?  It will likely avoid a whole lot of hassle.

Comment: The path contains ANSI characters, from 0 to 255. Some Unicode chars are converted to `'?'` which is a valid ASCII character. There is no way to tell what it was before. Just use Unicode as suggested.